# ReactJS' Higher Order Components error: "Unknown props"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-components

Yesterday, I was reading the React documentation on higher order components and I was trying to use some of the examples that they have. But, for me, it isn't working.

Here is a simple HOC I created just to wrap another component and see how this works. But since the very beginning, it never worked.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
export default function (enhacedComponent) {
  class Authenticate extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
    }
    render() {
      return <enhacedComponent {...this.props} />;
    }
  }
  return Authenticate;
}
```

It always returns me this error:

```
Warning: Unknown props `location`, `params`, `route`, `router`, `routeParams`, `routes` on <enhacedComponent> tag. Remove these props from the element.
```

When I check the HTML elements part in the console, I find that the actual value this HOC returns is `<enhacedComponent></enhacedComponent>`. So the wrapped component never got out!

So, in the end, the wrapped component never returns. Just a JSX version of what should be the argument of the HOC.

I think that since JSX is just a another syntax and the unique way to pass plain JavaScript is using `{}`, I tried to do this, to no success:

```
<{enhancedComponent} {...this.props }/>
```

I really don't know what to do or what I am doing wrong.

I'm using [this HOC reference](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html). I'm using Webpack 2 with webpack-dev-server as tools on Windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React thinks you're trying to pass these props to a DOM element and not a react component, which will give you the unknown props error. React interprets lower camel case as a DOM element, so `enhacedComponent` should be `EnhacedComponent`.

More info here:
https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/unknown-prop.html